# How to debug XSL errors

Tags: debugging, templates, xslt

I have a XSL transformation in Java which fails with:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at myXSL.countWidth()
        at myXSL.topLevel()
        at myXSL.transform()
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.AbstractTranslet.transform(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
```

where '**myXSL**' is the name of the XSL file (myXSL.xsl) and '**countWidth**' is a template

How can I debug what is causing the NPE in the XSL template?
Are there tools for this debugging?

Comment: Some time ago, I was [reading a book on Umbraco](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0470560827/ref=asc_df_04705608275169041?smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&tag=googlecouk06-21&linkCode=asn&creative=22206&creativeASIN=0470560827) with a section (well, a short paragraph in the Using XSTL section) explaining how to debug XSTL, and it went something like this: "do it right first time." Uuunbelievable!

Answer (score 0):

A NullPointerException here suggests a bug in the XSLT processor, not a bug in your code. So rather than debugging your code, you should be raising a bug on the processor or switching to a different processor. (I think there are options in Xalan-J to run in interpretive mode rather than compiled mode, which will probably cure it.)